# How do I uniquely identify computers visiting my web site?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I need to figure out a way uniquely identify each computer which visits the web site I am creating. Does anybody have any advice on how to achieve this?

Because i want the solution to work on all machines and all browsers (within reason) I am trying to create a solution using javascript.

Cookies will not do.

I need the ability to basically create a guid which is unique to a computer and repeatable, assuming no hardware changes have happened to the computer. Directions i am thinking of are getting the MAC of the network card and other information of this nature which will id the machine visiting the web site.

Comment: You can't get the mac of their network card - IP doens't contain that information, the best you can get is the IP address of their ISP gateway. For some ISPs that could be the same for all users in a given city.

Comment: The fact you do not want the user to be able to spoof it.  The answer is of course this can't be done without some priviledged component of yours installed on the users machine.

Comment: MAC addresses are trivially easy to spoof.  My crummy little wireless connection will pass through your MAC, substitute its own, or use the one you specify.

Comment: This can't be done - cookies are your best bet

Comment: Please read my answer in this page. i have a very good idea for this problem :)

Answer (score 111):

## Introduction

I don't know if there is or ever will be a way to uniquely identify machines using a browser alone. The main reasons are:

- You will need to save data on the users computer. This data can be
  deleted by the user any time. Unless you have a way to recreate this
  data which is unique for each and every machine then your stuck.
- Validation. You need to guard against spoofing, session hijacking, etc.

Even if there are ways to track a computer without using cookies there will always be a way to bypass it and software that will do this automatically. If you really need to track something based on a computer you will have to write a native application (Apple Store / Android Store / Windows Program / etc).

I might not be able to give you an answer to the question you asked but I can show you how to implement session tracking. With session tracking you try to track the browsing session instead of the computer visiting your site. By tracking the session, your database schema will look like this:

```
sesssion:
  sessionID: string
  // Global session data goes here
  
  computers: [{
     BrowserID: string
     ComputerID: string
     FingerprintID: string
     userID: string
     authToken: string
     ipAddresses: ["203.525....", "203.525...", ...]
     // Computer session data goes here
  }, ...]
```

Advantages of session based tracking:

1. For logged in users, you can always generate the same session id from the users `username` / `password` / `email`.
2. You can still track guest users using `sessionID`.
3. Even if several people use the same computer (ie cybercafe) you can track them separately if they log in.

Disadvantages of session based tracking:

1. Sessions are browser based and not computer based. If a user uses 2 different browsers it will result in 2 different sessions. If this is a problem you can stop reading here.
2. Sessions expire if user is not logged in. If a user is not logged in, then they will use a guest session which will be invalidated if user deletes cookies and browser cache.

## Implementation

There are many ways of implementing this. I don't think I can cover them all I'll just list my favorite which would make this an **opinionated answer**. Bear that in mind.

### Basics

I will track the session by using what is known as a forever cookie. This is data which will automagically recreate itself even if the user deletes his cookies or updates his browser. It will not however survive the user deleting both their cookies and their browsing cache.

To implement this I will use the browsers caching mechanism ([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.3)), WebStorage API ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)) and browser cookies ([RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage)).

### Legal

In order to utilize tracking ids you need to add them to both your privacy policy and your terms of use preferably under the sub-heading **Tracking**. We will use the following keys on both `document.cookie` and  `window.localStorage`:

- **_ga**: Google Analytics data
- **__utma**: Google Analytics tracking cookie
- **sid**: SessionID

Make sure you include links to your Privacy policy and terms of use on all pages that use tracking.

### Where do I store my session data?

You can either store your session data in your website database or on the users computer. Since I normally work on smaller sites (let than 10 thousand continuous connections) that use 3rd party applications (Google Analytics / Clicky / etc) it's best for me to store data on clients computer. This has the following advantages:

1. No database lookup / overhead / load / latency / space / etc.
2. User can delete their data whenever they want without the need to write me annoying emails.

and disadvantages:

1. Data has to be encrypted / decrypted and signed / verified which creates cpu overhead on client (not so bad) and server (bah!).
2. Data is deleted when user deletes their cookies and cache. (this is what I want really)
3. Data is unavailable for analytics when users go off-line. (analytics for currently browsing users only)

### UUIDS

- **BrowserID**: Unique id generated from the browsers user agent string. `Browser|BrowserVersion|OS|OSVersion|Processor|MozzilaMajorVersion|GeckoMajorVersion`
- **ComputerID**: Generated from users IP Address and HTTPS session key.
  `getISP(requestIP)|getHTTPSClientKey()`
- **FingerPrintID**: JavaScript based fingerprinting based on a modified [fingerprint.js](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/). `FingerPrint.get()`
- **SessionID**: Random key generated when user 1st visits site. `BrowserID|ComputerID|randombytes(256)`
- **GoogleID**: Generated from `__utma` cookie. `getCookie(__utma).uniqueid`

### Mechanism

The other day I was watching the [wendy williams show](http://www.wendyshow.com) with my girlfriend and was completely horrified when the host advised her viewers to delete their browser history at least once a month. Deleting browser history normally has the following effects:

1. Deletes history of visited websites.
2. Deletes cookies and `window.localStorage` (aww man).

Most modern browsers make this option readily available but fear not friends. For there is a solution. The browser has a caching mechanism to store scripts / images and other things. Usually even if we delete our history, this browser cache still remains. All we need is a way to store our data here. There are 2 methods of doing this. The better one is to use a SVG image and store our data inside its tags. This way data can still be extracted even if JavaScript is disabled using flash. However since that is a bit complicated I will demonstrate the other approach which uses JSONP ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP))

**example.com/assets/js/tracking.js** (actually tracking.php)

```
var now = new Date();
var window.__sid = "SessionID"; // Server generated

setCookie("sid", window.__sid, now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - 1));

if( "localStorage" in window ) {
  window.localStorage.setItem("sid", window.__sid);
}
```

Now we can get our session key any time:

`window.__sid || window.localStorage.getItem("sid") || getCookie("sid") || ""`

**How do I make tracking.js stick in browser?**

We can achieve this using [Cache-Control](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9), [Last-Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.29) and [ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.19) HTTP headers. We can use the `SessionID` as value for etag header:

```
setHeaders({
  "ETag": SessionID,
  "Last-Modified": new Date(0).toUTCString(),
  "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=31536000, s-max-age=31536000, must-revalidate"
})
```

`Last-Modified` header tells the browser that this file is basically never modified. `Cache-Control` tells proxies and gateways not to cache the document but tells the browser to cache it for 1 year.

The next time the browser requests the document, it will send `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers. We can use these to return a `304 Not Modified` response.

**example.com/assets/js/tracking.php**

```
$sid = getHeader("If-None-Match") ?: getHeader("if-none-match") ?: getHeader("IF-NONE-MATCH") ?: ""; 
$ifModifiedSince = hasHeader("If-Modified-Since") ?: hasHeader("if-modified-since") ?: hasHeader("IF-MODIFIED-SINCE");

if( validateSession($sid) ) {
  if( sessionExists($sid) ) {
    continueSession($sid);
    send304();
  } else {
    startSession($sid);
    send304();
  }
} else if( $ifModifiedSince ) {
  send304();
} else {
  startSession();
  send200();
}
```

Now every time the browser requests `tracking.js` our server will respond with a `304 Not Modified` result and force an execute of the local copy of `tracking.js`.

**I still don't understand. Explain it to me**

Lets suppose the user clears their browsing history and refreshes the page. The only thing left on the users computer is a copy of `tracking.js` in browser cache. When the browser requests `tracking.js` it recieves a `304 Not Modified` response which causes it to execute the 1st version of `tracking.js` it recieved. `tracking.js` executes and restores the `SessionID` that was deleted.

### Validation

Suppose Haxor X steals our customers cookies while they are still logged in. How do we protect them? Cryptography and Browser fingerprinting to the rescue. Remember our original definition for `SessionID` was:

```
BrowserID|ComputerID|randomBytes(256)
```

We can change this to:

```
Timestamp|BrowserID|ComputerID|encrypt(randomBytes(256), hk)|sign(Timestamp|BrowserID|ComputerID|randomBytes(256), hk)
```

Where `hk = sign(Timestamp|BrowserID|ComputerID, serverKey)`.

Now we can validate our `SessionID` using the following algorithm:

```
if( getTimestamp($sid) is older than 1 year ) return false;
if( getBrowserID($sid) !== createBrowserID($_Request, $_Server) ) return false;
if( getComputerID($sid) !== createComputerID($_Request, $_Server) return false;

$hk = sign(getTimestamp($sid) + getBrowserID($sid) + getComputerID($sid), $SERVER["key"]);

if( !verify(getTimestamp($sid) + getBrowserID($sid) + getComputerID($sid) + decrypt(getRandomBytes($sid), hk), getSignature($sid), $hk) ) return false;

return true;
```

Now in order for Haxor's attack to work they must:

1. Have same `ComputerID`. That means they have to have the same ISP provider as victim (Tricky). This will give our victim the opportunity to take legal action in their own country. Haxor must also obtain HTTPS session key from victim (Hard).
2. Have same `BrowserID`. Anyone can spoof User-Agent string (Annoying).
3. Be able to create their own fake `SessionID` (Very Hard). Volume atacks won't work because we use a time-stamp to generate encryption / signing key so basically its like generating a new key for each session. On top of that we encrypt random bytes so a simple dictionary attack is also out of the question.

We can improve validation by forwarding `GoogleID` and `FingerprintID` (via ajax or hidden fields) and matching against those.

```
if( GoogleID != getStoredGoodleID($sid) ) return false;
if( byte_difference(FingerPrintID, getStoredFingerprint($sid) > 10%) return false;
```

Comment: this is a beautiful answer by the way. So much information. I'm surprised you don't have more upvotes. I honestly can't believe the technique with svgs and jsonp exists, but it must. Is there no library that fallsback to such a technique when cookies/localStorage/sessionStorage are disabled?

Comment: Also, I wonder if there's an advanced version of this to simply use your cached tracking.js file (or multiple such files) to use it as essentially localStorage/cookies, i.e. to remember lots of data. The idea would be for a library to have methods like `storageFacade.setItem` and storageFacade.getItem`. And it tries to use localStorage, but fallsback to your technique when disabled. ..Perhaps the way it works is via a single file for "diffs" i.e. each time you call `setItem`. And then a `manifest` of all diffs created during the session that is automatically created every once in a while.

Comment: If the manifest was only created every once in a while, essentially it would limit the number of manifests created. And then later in javascript you could try to request all the possible manifests created, and then use the latest one to rebuild the state from the diff snapshots. If we just had diffs, there could be hundreds or thousands and that might be a performance problem to try to fetch them all until one failed. I.e. you fetch the diff or manifest incrementally: manifest-1.js, manifest-2.js, etc, until one fails (because it doesn't exist). Which means u have all the manifests (or diffs)

Comment: @faceyspacey.com Sorry no libraries ever. You have to code and constantly update your own custom solution. Think about it. As soon as you develop a lib for this all the add blockers/browsers/etc would immediately counter it. The only reason this works is because it relies on a very important core browser feature that they simply won't remove/disable: CACHING. I keep losing my logins and passwords. And since I don't ask a lot of questions anymore, I don't need to answer many so I can leave bounties with reputation. I just saw this and realized there was no real answer.

Answer (score 62):

These people have developed a fingerprinting method for recognising a user with a high level of accuracy:

https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf

> We  investigate  the  degree  to  which  modern  web  browsers
> are  subject  to  “device  fingerprinting”  via  the  version  and  configuration information that they will transmit to websites upon request. We
> implemented one possible fingerprinting algorithm, and collected these
> fingerprints from a large sample of browsers that visited our test side,
> [panopticlick.eff.org](https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/panopticlick.eff.org). We observe that the distribution of our finger-
> print  contains  at  least  18.1  bits  of  entropy,  meaning  that  if  we  pick  a
> browser  at  random,  at  best  we  expect  that  only  one  in  286,777  other
> browsers will share its fingerprint. Among browsers that support Flash
> or Java, the situation is worse, with the average browser carrying at least
> 18.8 bits of identifying information. 94.2% of browsers with Flash or Java
> were unique in our sample.

By observing returning visitors, we estimate how rapidly browser fingerprints might change over time. In our sample, fingerprints changed quite
rapidly, but even a simple heuristic was usually able to guess when a fingerprint was an “upgraded” version of a previously observed browser’s
fingerprint, with 99.1% of guesses correct and a false positive rate of only
0.86%.

> 

We discuss what privacy threat browser fingerprinting poses in practice,
and what countermeasures may be appropriate to prevent it. There is a
tradeoff between protection against fingerprintability and certain kinds of
debuggability, which in current browsers is weighted heavily against privacy. Paradoxically, anti-fingerprinting privacy technologies can be self-
defeating if they are not used by a sufficient number of people; we show
that  some  privacy  measures  currently  fall  victim  to  this  paradox,  but
others do not.

Comment: I am a developer, I came here to look for a quick solution or a small code snippet. This document does not show how to implement it. I want to know how do I implement this so I can track unique users for my site.

Comment: @Oliver You are correct. This does not give you the answer on a plate. It requires further reading, understanding of all the issues involved and why a simple code snippet is unlikely to ever completely work. An enterprising developer might write a library which does all the hard work, and enable people searching for a "quick solution" to benefit in the future.

Comment: The answer is also link-only. A summary of the techniques described in the PDF would be appreciated in case the PDF becomes unavailable.

Comment: See my answer here for an open source package and easy-ish way to implement fingerprinting https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536192/3650835

Comment: So I better make a resilient "cookie" with a random big number :D

Comment: it's better to directly post the answer not a link to a file that need further reading and further knowledge.

Answer (score 31):

It's not possible to identify the computers accessing a web site without the cooperation of their owners. If they let you, however, you can store a cookie to identify the machine when it visits your site again. The key is, the visitor is in control; they can remove the cookie and appear as a new visitor any time they wish.

Comment: If he visits your site with 3 different browsers, then he will have 3 different cookies since cookies are not shared among apps. Further, if he uses DHCP rather than a static IP address, he probably will not have the same IP address for his computer for long.

Comment: Yes and no. Browser fingerprinting identifies a browser profile with a high degree of probability, but it's not the absolute one-to-one identification sought in this question. It is also fairly simple (but perhaps not *easy*) for a savvy user to circumvent deliberately if they wish.

Answer (score 29):

A possibility is using [flash cookies](http://yro.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/10/14/1656251&from=rss):

- Ubiquitous availability (95 percent of visitors will probably have flash)
- You can store more data per cookie (up to 100 KB)
- Shared across browsers, so more likely to uniquely identify a machine
- Clearing the browser cookies does not remove the flash cookies.

You'll need to build a small (hidden) flash movie to read and write them.

Whatever route you pick, make sure your users opt IN to being tracked, otherwise you're invading their privacy and become one of the bad guys.

Comment: Many user use Flashblock. Flash will activated from the user with a click if he want see it.

Comment: There are methods to remove the cookies, but they are beyond the average user. There are pages on Adobe's website for viewing and removing LSO's (Local Shared Object http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) although for Firefox users the Objection add-on is the easiest method to remove them

Comment: I think this is one of the best solutions. Youtube, Google etc. use LSOs to fight abuse.

Comment: Also this won't work in Chrome's and posibly Firefox's incognito mode, because the browser deletes flash cookies also on exit when you are in this mode.

Comment: Flash cookies are as easily deleted as HTTP cookies in modern versions of Firefox and Chrome: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object): `Adobe announced that Flash Player 10.3 enables Mozilla Firefox 4 and "future releases of Apple Safari and Google Chrome" to delete local shared objects,[11] so since version 4, Firefox treats LSOs the same way as HTTP cookies - deletion rules that previously applied only to HTTP cookies now also apply to LSOs.`

Comment: The situation has changed in the past nine years. Nowadays, 95 percent of users aren't even on desktop, and mobile never really embraced Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that [Flash will be end-of-life in 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash#End_of_life), and so this isn't a viable option long-term.Even if the answer is 10 years old, I think it's worth mentioning to anyone who stumbles across this answer through Google.

Comment: 95 percent of visitors will probably have flash... in the year 2008?

Answer (score 24):

There is a popular method called canvas fingerprinting, described in this scientific article: [The Web Never Forgets:
Persistent Tracking Mechanisms in the Wild](https://securehomes.esat.kuleuven.be/~gacar/persistent/the_web_never_forgets.pdf). Once you start looking for it, you'll be surprised how frequently it is used. The method creates a unique fingerprint, which is consistent for each browser/hardware combination.

The article also reviews other persistent tracking methods, like evercookies, respawning http and Flash cookies, and cookie syncing.

**More info about canvas fingerprinting here:**

- [Pixel Perfect: Fingerprinting Canvas in HTML5](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/canvas.pdf)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting

Comment: so if two device are identical (same batch computers, same os, same browsers), the fingerprints are same, right?

Comment: The actual question here is were is the javascript library I can drop in my code to use this. Reading a ton of theory doesn't solve problems that must be solved within the next 60 minutes.

Answer (score 21):

You may want to try setting a unique ID in an evercookie (it will work cross browser, see their FAQs):
http://samy.pl/evercookie/

There is also a company called ThreatMetrix that is used by a lot of big companies to solve this problem:
http://threatmetrix.com/our-solutions/solutions-by-product/trustdefender-id/
They are quite expensive and some of their other products aren't very good, but their device id works well.

Finally, there is this open source jquery implementation of the panopticlick idea:
https://github.com/carlo/jquery-browser-fingerprint
It looks pretty half baked right now but could be expanded upon.

Hope it helps!

Comment: + 1 - Brian - Great information! This all has proven very useful. Thankyou.
Do add more information if you have learn't any more since.

Comment: Regarding evercookie. Tried with Opera. Set cookies, then deleted all history from Opera, then closed Opera, opened again clicked on `Click to rediscover cookies` and see either null or undefined. So this does not work for me

Comment: Tried the sample page with iOS Safari Private mode and Desktop Chrome incognito, the cookie can't be retrieved after browser restart.

Comment: Access to samy.pl was denied

Answer (score 12):

There is only a small amount of information that you can get via an HTTP connection.

1. IP - But as others have said, this is not fixed for many, if not most Internet users due to their ISP's dynamic allocation policies.
2. Useragent String - Nearly all browsers send what kind of browser they are with every request. However, this can be set by the user in many browsers today.
3. Collection of request fields - There are other fields sent with each request, such as supported encodings, etc. These, if used in the aggregate can help to ID a user's machine, but again are browser dependent and can be changed.
4. Cookies - Setting a cookie is another way to identify a machine, or more specifically a browser on a machine, but as others have said, these can be deleted, or turned off by the users, and are only applicable on a browser, not a machine.

So, the correct response is that you cannot achieve what you would live via the HTTP over IP protocols alone. However, using a combination of cookies, as well as IP, and the fields in the HTTP request, you have a good chance at guessing, sort of, what machine it is. Users tend to use only one browser, and often from one machine, so this may be fairly relieable, but this will vary depending on the audience...techies are more likely to mess with this stuff, and use more machines/browsers.  Additionally, this could even be coupled with some attempt to geo-locate the IP, and use that data as well. But in any case, there is no solution that will be correct all of the time.

Answer (score 11):

There are flaws with both cookie and non-cookie approaches.  But if you can forgive the shortcomings of the cookie approach, here's an idea.

If you're already using Google Analytics on your site, then you don't need to write code to track unique users yourself.  Google Analytics does that for you via the `__utma` cookie value, as described in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsCookies).  And by reusing this value you're not creating additional cookie payload, which has efficiency benefits with page requests.

And you could write some code easily enough to access that value, or use [this script's](http://www.dannytalk.com/read-google-analytics-cookie-script/) `getUniqueId()` function.

Comment: Will i get same id using `getUniqueId()` in different browsers in same machine?

Comment: If the user is logged into their Google account, you should.

Comment: Do you have a link to something explaining what they use to identify a unique user? Eg: is it more thorough than simply using an IP address? Do they use a number of parameters?

Answer (score 8):

As with the previous solutions cookies are a good method, be aware that they identify **browsers** though. If I visited a website in Firefox and then in Internet Explorer cookies would be stored for both attempts seperately. Some users also disable cookies (but more people disable JavaScript).

Another method to consider would be I.P. and hostname identification (be aware these can vary for dial-up/non-static IP users, AOL also uses blanket IPs). However since this only identifies networks this might not work as well as cookies.

Comment: Good point with IP address identifying point of access to network - with NAT, there could be entire *countries* hidden behind a single IP address and you'd be none the wiser. With the IPv4 address shortage, you'll still see pretty large companies or schools/universities sharing a single IP address for its outbound Internet traffic.

Answer (score 6):

The suggestions to use cookies aside, the only comprehensive set of identifying attributes available to interrogate are contained in the HTTP request header. So it is possible to use some subset of these to create a pseudo-unique identifier for a user agent (i.e., browser). Further, most of this information is possibly already being logged in the so-called "access log" of your web server software by default and, if not, can be easily configured to do so.  Then, a utlity could be developed that simply scans the content of this log, creating *fingerprints* of each request comprised of, say, the IP address and User Agent string, etc.  The more data available, even including the contents of specific cookies, adds to the quality of the uniqueness of this fingerprint.  Though, as many others have stated already, the HTTP protocol doesn't make this 100% foolproof - at best it can only be a fairly good indicator.

Answer (score 6):

> When i use a machine which has never visited my online banking web site i get asked for additional authentification. then, if i go back a second time to the online banking site i dont get asked the additional authentification...i deleted all cookies in IE and relogged onto my online banking site fully expecting to be asked the authentification questions again. to my surprise i was not asked. doesnt this lead one to believe the bank is doing some kind of pc tagging which doesnt involve cookies?

This is a pretty common type of authentication used by banks.

Say you're accessing your bank website via example-isp.com. The first time you're there, you'll be asked for your password, as well as additional authentication. Once you've passed, the bank knows that user "thatisvaliant" is authenticated to access the site via example-isp.com.

In the future, it won't ask for extra authentication (beyond your password) when you're accessing the site via example-isp.com. If you try to access the bank via another-isp.com, the bank will go through the same routine again.

So to summarize, what the bank's identifying is your ISP and/or netblock, based on your IP address. Obviously not every user at your ISP is you, which is why the bank still asks you for your password.

Have you ever had a credit card company call to verify that things are OK when you use a credit card in a different country? Same concept.

Answer (score 4):

Really, what you want to do cannot be done because the protocols do not allow for this.  If static IPs were universally used then you might be able to do it.  They are not, so you cannot.

If you really want to identify *people*, have them log in.

Since they will probably be moving around to different pages on your web site, you need a way to keep track of them as they move about.

So long as they are logged in, and you are tracking their session within your site via cookies/link-parameters/beacons/whatever, you can be pretty sure that they are using the same computer during that time.

Ultimately, it is incorrect to say this tells you which computer they are using if your users are not using your own local network and do not have static IP addresses.

If what you want to do is being done with the cooperation of the users and there is only one user per cookie and they use a single web browser, just use a cookie.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)

```
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
  console.log(result) // a hash, representing your device fingerprint
  console.log(components) // an array of FP components
  //submit hash and JSON object to the server 
})
```

After that you can check all your users against existing and check JSON similarity, so even if their fingerprint mutates, you still can track them

Answer (score 3):

> Because i want the solution to work on all machines and all browsers (within reason) I am trying to create a solution using javascript.

Isn't that a really good reason *not* to use javascript?

As others have said - cookies are probably your best option - just be aware of the limitations.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the verdict is i cannot programmatically uniquely identify a computer which is visiting my web site.

I have the following question. When i use a machine which has never visited my online banking web site i get asked for additional authentification. then, if i go back a second time to the online banking site i dont get asked the additional authentification. reading the answers to my question i decided it must be a cookie involved. therefore, i deleted all cookies in IE and relogged onto my online banking site fully expecting to be asked the authentification questions again. to my surprise i was not asked. doesnt this lead one to believe the bank is doing some kind of pc tagging which doesnt involve cookies?

further, after much googling today i found the following company who claims to sell a solution which does uniquely identify machines which visit a web site. http://www.the41.com/products.asp.

i appreciate all the good information if you could clarify further this conflicting information i found i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Based on this:

http://www.the41.com/download/PCPrint%20for%20FI%20Product%20Overview_SL08PCT%20FSv1.pdf 

It looks like their solution is to make the user download a piece of software which creates a unique identifier based on the machine and ties it to some login credentials.

Comment: As mentioned already, you didn't rule out your bank using a Flash cookie. How to clear Flash cookies and other discussion about the issue: http://tips.vlaurie.com/2007/10/24/how-you-are-secretly-tracked-with-flash-cookies/

Comment: My guess:  The bank probably trusts that you are you if you (1) know your username, (2) know your password, and either (3a) have their cookie, or else (3b) come from an IP address they've previously associated with you.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using a combination of cookies and flash cookies. Create a GUID and store it in a cookie. If the cookie doesn't exist, try to read it from the flash cookie. If it's still not found, create it and write it to the flash cookie. This way you can share the same GUID across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think cookies might be what you are looking for; this is how most websites uniquely identify visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies won't be useful for determining unique visitors. A user could clear cookies and refresh the site - he then is classed as a new user again.

I think that the best way to go about doing this is to implement a server side solution (as you will need somewhere to store your data). Depending on the complexity of your needs for such data, you will need to determine what is classed as a unique visit. A sensible method would be to allow an IP address to return the following day and be given a unique visit. Several visits from one IP address in one day shouldn't be counted as uniques.

Using PHP, for example, it is trivial to get the IP address of a visitor, and store it in a text file (or a sql database).

A server side solution will work on all machines, because you are going to track the user when he first loads up your site. Don't use javascript, as that is meant for client side scripting, plus the user may have disabled it in any case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My wife and I browse from four different computers behind a NAT firewall at home.  We show up as having the same IP, so by your scheme we show up as the same user.

Comment: What if in mysql to write additional variables (mentioned here https://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf)? So ip address would be the same, but some other characteristics may be different.

Answer (score 1):

I will give my ideas starting from simpler to more complex.
In all the above you can create sessions and the problem essentialy translates to match session with request.

a) (difficulty: easy) use client hardware to store explicitely  a session id/hash of some sort (there are quite some privace/security issues so make sure you hash anything you store ), solutions include:

- cookies storage
- browser storage/webDB/  (more exotic browser solutions )
- extensions with permission  to store things in files.

The above suffer from the fact the the user can just empty his cache in case he doesn want.

b) (difficulty: medium) Login based authentication.
Most modern web frameworks provide such solution the core idea is you let the user voluntarily identify himself, quite straghtforward but adds complexity in the architecture.

The above suffer from additional complexity and making essentially non public content.

c)(difficulty: hard -R&D)  Identification based on metadata, (browser ip/language /browser / and other privace invasice stuff so make sure you let your users know or you miay get sued )
non perfect solution can get more complicated (a user typing with specific frequency or using mouse with specific patterns ? you even apply ML solutions ).
The claimed solutions

The most powerful since the user even without wanting explicitely he can be identified. It is straight  invasion of privacy(see GDPR) and not perfect eg. ip can change .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the user to be in control, you can't. The web doesn't work like that, the best you can hope for is some heuristics.

If it is an option to force your visitor to install some software and use TCPA you may be able to pull something off.

Answer (score -1):

My post might not be a solution, but I can provide an example, where this feature has been implemented.

If you visit the signup page of `www.supertorrents.org` for the first time from you computer, it's fine. But if you refresh the page or open the page again, it identifies you've previously visited the page. The real beauty comes here - it identifies even if you re-install Windows or other OS.

I read somewhere that they store the CPU ID. Although I couldn't find how do they do it, I seriously doubt it, and they might use MAC Address to do it.

I'll definitely share if I find *how* to do it.

Comment: www.supertorrents.org is dead

Answer (score -3):

**A Trick:**

1. Create 2 Registration Pages:

   **First Registration Page:** without any email or security check (just with username and password)

   **Second Registration Page:** with high security level (email verification request and security image and etc.)
2. For customer satisfaction, and easy registration, default
   registration page should be the **(First Registration Page)** but in the
   **(First Registration Page)** there is a hidden restriction. It's IP
   Restriction. If an IP tried to register for second time, (for example less than 1 hour) instead of
   showing the block page. you can show the **(Second Registration Page)**
   automatically.
3. in the **(First Registration Page)** you can set (for example: block 2
   attempts from 1 ip for just 1 hour or 24 hours) and after (for example) 1 hour, you can open access from that ip automatically

Please note: **(First Registration Page)** and **(Second Registration Page)** should not be in separated pages. you make just 1 page. (for example: register.php) and make it smart to switch between First PHP Style and Second PHP Style

Comment: Mahdi Jazini .All are right but my question is how u identify the IP address of the client machine.Thanks.