# Click counting, limiting, and disabling

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cookies, click

Is it possible to use JQuery & PHP to create a "like" button that a user could click and it would add +1 to a "number of likes" database (or even text file) and disable the "like" button for that user so that the user could only click it once?  I was browsing around and found some information about writing cookies with JQuery:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html

Perhaps, when a like button is clicked, it could write a cookie to the user's computer that would prevent them from future clicks?  It just basically needs to be that the user could click the like button, it adds a count to some type of database, and it disables the button for the user.  Pretty simple I would imagine - there may already be some type of plugin for this, but I haven't found any.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember never to trust your users, or JavaScript (client-side)-based security.

Comment: Right.  Then maybe a more purely PHP solution with JQuery effects would be a better option.  Maybe limit the clicks based off of IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $.post('count.php');
});
```

though the user can just reload the page, so any real validation needs to happen on the php side.

Comment: That makes sense.  And the validation should limit it by IP address then?  Or is there another way?

Comment: @Dan: The best way is if your users are registered on the site.. Otherwise, a combination of Cookies and an IP history would do well.

Comment: Do not restrict by IP address alone since it is incredibly common for many users to be on one IP. How crappy would it be if one person on a network voted and everyone else was blocked ;) Instead restrict by session, other cookie or username.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will keep this in mind when I build the validation for it.  I'd hate to build a complete user registration system for this one page, but sessions/cookies could be a good alternative option.  Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: @Dan, you might want to take a read of this page: [how to uniquely identify computers visiting my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site) and [Flash cookies](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=flash+cookies+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: just have count.php store username/likeditem pair along with the tally.  ajax will handle the immediate removal of like button, checking the db when rendering the page will do it in the future

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.  It allows you to bind an event for only one invocation.  Here's an example I'd run on page load.

```
if (likedBefore) {
  $("button").addClass("liked");
}
else {
  $("button").one("click", function() {
     $(this).addClass("liked");
     $.post("count.php");
  });
}
```

Validating server side is a bit more difficult.  It really depends on how secure you need this to be.