# How to get MAC address client side with js,flash,java or etc. with crossbrowser method

Tags: cross-browser, mac-address

How can I get the MAC address (or something unique for each pc -at least standard user knowledge level-) from client side with js,flash,java or etc. using a crossbrowser method?
You probably know when we are coding a poll we should use cookies to prevent multiple voting.
 I couldn't find a crossbrowser javascript method (without MS IEs activex). Javascript, java applet or flash files will be welcome.
Thank you
Caglar

Comment: Another use case is when a web app needs to remember a file location in the PC's local file system - for example the location of their dropbox root so that a file:/// url can be used for dropbox files. Modern browsers sync cookies which messes up this concept (dropbox files may be in different locations on synced machines); whereas a MAC address based system with cookies would allow a distinction.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no standard Javascript APIs for getting a mac address.

It *is* possible to get this information using a Java applet, but it would need to be signed and have a policy file in order to access hardware info, and it wouldn't really be transparent to the user. See [Getting MAC address on a web page using a Java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467905/getting-mac-address-on-a-web-page-using-a-java-applet)

If you just need to track a client, the most reliable thing you can do is use a combination of APIs available to Javascript to create a persistent cookie. It's possible to create a very resilient cookie using a combination of standard HTTP cookies, session storage APIs, caching tricks, and plugins. Evercookie is a great example: http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with JavaScript. Otherwise any one can lure you to visit their website will be able to peek your MAC address, and that would be a security issue. You can only do it through plug-ins. And the browser will have to prompt user to explicitly allow that plugin first.