# MAC address value shows null

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the following javascript code to get MAC address in my master page. In the code behind of master.cs page, in Page_Load() method I write "string mac = inpHide.Value.ToString();" to get that mac address. But when I debug, I only get null value. I need to use that value in my global.asax. Any help?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function MACAddress() {
        var locator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        var service = locator.ConnectServer(".");
        var properties = service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        var e = new Enumerator(properties);
        var MACaddress = '';
        for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
            var p = e.item();
            if (p.MACAddress) {
                MACaddress = MACaddress + p.MACAddress + ',';
            }
        }
        MACaddress = MACaddress.substring(0, MACaddress.length - 1);
        var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
        document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = MACaddress;        
    }
</script>
```

In my master page body:

```
<div><input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server"/></div>
```

Comment: You've declared the function, where do you call it?

Comment: Sorry I call it in my body: <body onload="MACAddress()"> of my master page.

Comment: This looks like VB-Script to me. You are sure this is javascript??

Comment: Yes this is javascript. I tested it to a html page. The code I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784258/getting-mac-address-in-mozilla-activexobject-is-not-working

Comment: Did you read the answers to that other question?

Comment: Yes I read that. But I don't need that solution coz I only want to get MAC for IE(not other browsers). Please answer my actual problem as I mentioned as a question.