# AnyOne can help me to get client mac address and system name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

AnyOne can help me to get client mac address and system name in mvc or  C#?
when anyone can access my website

Comment: Check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661829/5621827) for mac address and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768219/5621827) for system name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245571/how-to-get-the-client-system-mac-id-and-other-details-like-ip-address-etc

Comment: Sorry But its not working its give me server mac address . But i want clinet address please help

Answer (score 0):

Collecting client's mac address is not possible due to firewall, proxy, because ISP generic addresses are being given.

But you can grab the ip address using either

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or using request's server variable collection

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

To get the computer name, use the below variable

```
var remoteMachineName = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST");
```

But if you want to more details about how these values can be collected, you can visit the below article

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/2088/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine

Hope this helps.