# How to run applet with policy permissions in Java to read the MAC address

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I'm trying to develop an applet in NetBeans which can read the MAC address.

So here is my directory structure

[image]

Here is my *UPDATED Code*

> MacAddrApplet.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

/**
 *
 * @author jay.patel
 */
public class MacAddressApplet extends JApplet {

    public static String getMacFromInterface(NetworkInterface ni) throws SocketException {
        byte mac[] = ni.getHardwareAddress();

        if (mac != null) {
            StringBuilder macAddress = new StringBuilder("");
            String sep = "";
            for (byte o : mac) {
                macAddress.append(sep).append(String.format("%02X", o));
                sep = ":";
            }
            return macAddress.toString();
        }

        return "";
    }

    public static String[] getInterfaces() {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (nis.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface ni = nis.nextElement();
                if (ni.isUp() && !ni.isLoopback() && !ni.isVirtual()) {
                    String mac = getMacFromInterface(ni);
                    String str = ni.getDisplayName() + ";" + mac;
                    result.add(str);
                }
            }
            return result.toArray(new String[0]);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("SocketException:: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return new String[0];
    }

    public static String getInterfacesJSON() {
        try {
            String macs[] = getInterfaces();

            String sep = "";
            StringBuilder macArray = new StringBuilder("['");
            for (String mac : macs) {
                macArray.append(sep).append(mac);
                sep = "','";
            }
            macArray.append("']");

            return macArray.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return "[]";
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
         AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {
                String macs[] = getInterfaces();

                for (String mac : macs) {
                    System.out.println(" Interfaces = " + mac);
                }

                System.out.println(" Interfaces JSON = " + getInterfacesJSON());
                g.drawString("MAC: " + getInterfacesJSON(), 100, 100);
                return null;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

> MacAddrApplet.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

    <P><APPLET codebase="classes" code="MacAddrApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET></P>

    <HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
```

> applet.policy

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

---

When I try to run my applet from `Run -> Run File` it works perfectly fine and shows my Mac address in it, with this log that I'm printing

```
Interfaces = en1;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Interfaces JSON = ['en1;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX']
```

But when I try to run it using

```
appletviewer build/MacAddrApplet.html
```

it prints

```
Interfaces = en1;
Interfaces JSON = ['en1;']
```

**How can I solve this issue??**

P.S. I think it's happening because it's not using the permissions of `applet.policy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I figured out what's wrong with the terminal command

```
appletviewer build/MacAddrApplet.html
```

because if you see the `project.properties` file located in `nbproject` folder, at the end part, you'll see

```
run.jvmargs=-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy
```

So when I run the applet using `Run -> Run File` Netbeans internally took care of everything and hence the applet is running perfectly fine.

**But**, in case of the terminal, I need to specify the `policy file` explicitly (This is what I want to know when I asked the question!), So run the applet with this command and it will work fine...

```
appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy build/MacAddrApplet.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a problem with Applet permissions. It's primarily a good old-fashioned bug in your code :-).

Read the docs for [`NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress--) - the method may return `null`:

> returns: a byte array containing the address, or null if the address
>   doesn't exist, is not accessible or a security manager is set and the
>   caller does not have the permission
>   NetPermission("getNetworkInformation")

You forgot the null check when calling it, thus the NullPointerException.

As to *why* you get back `null` - that could be because of the SecurityManager (as the docs indicate), but in this case the problem is probably that `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` gave you the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address, and consequently the interface you got is the loopback interface. The loopback interface, being a simulated interface, does not have a MAC address, so `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` will return `null`.

---

Taking a step backwards, your first mistake is to use `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`. A computer can have multiple network interfaces, with multiple IP addresses (for example, a wired Ethernet interface and a WLAN interface, plus virtual interfaces such as loopback, or for a VPN client). **So, in general, there is not "the MAC address", but 0-n MAC addresses, depending on system configuration.**

You need to figure out how you choose your MAC address among those available. You can use `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` to retrieve all interfaces the system has (even the deactivated ones), then go through them to decide which one you like (and which one has a MAC address).

Comment: I've updated the code, so now it won't give null pointer and I'm storing in an array so it'll handle multiple Mac address issue, but still when I try to run `appletviewer build/MacAddrApplet.html` it's not printing mac address

Comment: @JayPatel: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not intended as a debugging service. The code looks better at first glance, but you'll have to debug it yourself to narrow down the issue - then you can ask a new question if you are still stumped.