# Shared cookie across browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am currently investigating ways to be able to tell if our website has seen a "device" before.

I know how to set normal cookies in Rails and that would work for a browser.

But I was wondering if it is possible to use [LSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object) or any other mechanism which would allow me to detect a particular "device" across browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: Flash “cookies” are browser independent …

Comment: @CBroe Yes that is exactly what I am looking for! But haven't been able to find a tutorial yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to use flash cookies, since you are identifying a device, it won't work with mobile devices (even android deprecated flash).

You can try [this approach](https://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf) to identify the user, still take notice of "Do not track me" options in browsers.

Another option you have, which works specially good for mobile browsers are the proprietary HTTP headers used. Check [this article](http://mobiforge.com/developing/blog/useful-x-headers) where it lists some useful ones, specially the "x-wsb-identity".