# How can I get client's computers mac address or identifier of a machine

Tags: javascript, php, windows

I need to stop multiple login from same computer even for different user. This is why need client machine's unique identifier or mac address. How can achieve this? I have tried following but not work. Its return `NULL`

```
$ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$x = shell_exec('arp -a ' . escapeshellarg($ip));
```

I need this feature that will work on all browser. Any Idea?

I have seen some solution only work in IE. But how can get solution in all modern browsers?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site

Comment: Here is a post with the problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the MAC address of a user via pure Javascript. You may be able to get it with some browser plugins or similar hacks, but there's no standard way to obtain this information.