# JS get unique device Id - No PhoneGap/Cordova or cookies

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier

I will have 14 devices visiting a web page for a period of 30 day. I have no access to the devices, and want to count the visits from each device. I am coding the server side PHP too.

I don't want to use PhoneGap/Cordova or cookies. Is there a pure JS solution?

IMEI, MAC address, serial number, some fingerprint based on hardware ... anything at all, so long as I can distinguish them.

---

[Update] these will be new devices, fresh from the box, so fingerprinting can't rely on browser history, installed apps, etc. They will be identical except for hardware.

Comment: Devices can have their parts replaced. What is the device? The processor, the SIM card, the network adaptor, its storage, ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uniquely identify computers visiting my web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site)

Comment: Those all use either cookies or browser fingerprinting, which I can't use. I updated the question.