# Obtain Computer Name via Chrome or Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, activex, microsoft-edge, mac-address, computer-name

The requirement is that we want to identify a device running windows 10 from browsers like Chrome or Edge. The unique information of a computer I have come up with is the computer name or Mac address and I know I could access these information through ActiveXObject from IE. The problem is that neither Chrome nor Edge supports ActiveX. So here I want your help on two questions. 
1, Could my requirement be satisfied at all?
2, If the answer to first question is positive, then how?

Any useful comment would be appreciated.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site