# How can we get a unique machine id or some id from all the users to see whether they are updated to latest angular version deployed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We are trying to record all our client angular application version. each user might be using different machines to use our application. We want to confirm that all our clients are updated with our latest release. I was able to pull the version of the update from SwUpdate Service. How can we know precisely from which machine is updated and which machine is not? 
Is there any way to get some unique id from the machine, browser or any other source. So we can identify that user machine is not updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uniquely identify computers visiting my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site)

Comment: This question is not "unclear what you're asking", why is it being closed for that reason?  (I'm retracting my close vote to avoid it being closed for the wrong reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been a lot of privacy work done on the internet to ensure that you CAN'T (reliably) get any such unique ID.  So, while this might be possible, it will be very hard (you'll be in an arms race with your more privacy-minded users).

What I would recommend instead is that you pull the version by itself, from each client, without trying to identify which client is which.  If you get any reports of the wrong version, then you know that some of your clients are not updated (and you can use JavaScript to show messages to just those people who aren't updated, based purely on their not-updated status).  If you don't get any reports of the wrong version within a reasonable timeframe, then it's probably fair to assume that everyone is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This helps.